# running electric to my detached garage

Tags: electrical-panel

I'm looking to run electric to my garage . It is about 100' from the garage to the main panel in the house I was going to put in a sub panel in the garage . The only I couldn't  find is a 60 amp . I was going to run 10-3 w/bond . I have a table saw lights that I'm looking to use it for . will that work and what size breaker should I use ?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You say: "The only I couldn't find is a 60 amp".  Does that mean you DID or your DID NOT find a 60 A panel?

What power requirement to you have for the garage?  Do you need 60 A?

10 ga. wire, however, is NOT suitable for a 100' run at 60 A.  You'll need 4 AWG copper or 2 AWG Aluminum (which is likely less expensive).

Comment: What sort of 60A thing are you having trouble finding?

Comment: Wiring detached garages, outbuildings and shops is probably one of the most frequently asked questions on this site. Some are even 100’ away.  10/3 limits you to 30 amp?  How much current does your tablesaw draw?   Any needs for future expansion?

Answer (score 1):

### You don't need a 60A panel.  In fact it's a bad idea.

Your panel needs to have a shutoff switch*.  It doesn't need a main breaker.  Although... a main breaker happens to work as a shutoff switch.

Since you're using it only as a shutoff switch and not as a breaker, the breaker size doesn't matter at all.  You can use any panel you please, and in fact, we recommend a large one.  That way you have enough panel *spaces* for all your needs and on into the future.

There's nothing worse than running out of spaces in your panel, and now is the time to avoid this - before you buy your panel.  Spend a few extra dollars and get one with a lot of spaces.  Most likely, its main breaker will be larger than 60A.  Like I said, that's fine.

Your wiring will be protected by the feed breaker in the main panel.  For 10/3 w/ground cable, you must use a 30A breaker.   That may suit your needs.  However if you run 6/3 w/ ground cable, you can use a 60A breaker.

Remember you must trench direct burial cable to 25", so you have 24" cover over top of the cable, with sand or sifted dirt around it so a rock doesn't dig into the cable.

Also you will need grounding rods at the garage, even though you are running a ground wire.  You must do both.

---

* It needs a shutoff switch because it's in a detached garage.